# JavaScript or CSS function to close menu when click on any option

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I don't know how to close the menu when I click or select an item. The muenu is CSS only but I heve no problem by adding JavaScript code although I would prefer to keep it CSS only

https://codepen.io/nigarcia/pen/wQdVBW

```html
<div class="navigation">
      <input type="checkbox" class="nav-check" id="navi-toggle">

      <label for="navi-toggle" class="nav-btn">
          <span class="nav-icon">&nbsp;</span>
      </label>

      <div class="nav-bg">&nbsp;</div>

      <nav class="nav-nav">
          <ul class="nav-list">              
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: how do you open it ? your CSS is missing, to make this work

Comment: Are you using a framework or something? share your javascript code.

Comment: no its a css only menu working with `input:checked ~ .nav-mav { display:block;}` or something

Comment: I added the link to the entire code at codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JavaScript solution. All code is commented.

```js
var elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link'); /* create an array of your '.nav-link' li */

elementsArray.forEach(function(myBtn) {
    /*add a listener to every element of this array */
    myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()/* prevent default link behaviour */
       document.getElementById("navi-toggle").checked = false; /* unchecked your checkbox */
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-check {
  display: none; 
}

.nav-btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2000;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
  
.nav-bg {
  height: 3.8rem;
  width: 3.8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(224, 224, 224), rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.9));
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1); 
}
  
.nav-nav {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Northshire Script, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1500;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55); 
}

.nav-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; 
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 1rem; 
}

.nav-link:link, .nav-link:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 7rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .4s; 
}
  .nav-link:link span, .nav-link:visited span {
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    display: inline-block; 
  }

.nav-link:hover, .nav-link:active {
  background-position: 100%;
  color: #55c57a;
  transform: translateX(1rem); 
}

.nav-check:checked ~ .nav-bg {
  transform: scale(80);
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.nav-check:checked ~ .nav-nav {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%; 
}

.nav-check::after ~ .nav-bg {
  transform: scale(0); 
}

.nav-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.9rem; 
}
  .nav-icon, .nav-icon::before, .nav-icon::after {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    display: inline-block; 
  }
  .nav-icon::before, .nav-icon::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .2s; 
  }
  .nav-icon::before {
    top: -.8rem; 
  }
  .nav-icon::after {
    top: .8rem; 
  }

.nav-btn:hover .nav-icon::before {
  top: -1rem; 
}

.nav-btn:hover .nav-icon::after {
  top: 1rem; 
}

.nav-check:checked + .nav-btn .nav-icon {
  background-color: transparent; 
}

.nav-check:checked + .nav-btn .nav-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  top: 0; 
}

.nav-check:checked + .nav-btn .nav-icon::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-135deg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <input type="checkbox" class="nav-check" id="navi-toggle">

    <label for="navi-toggle" class="nav-btn">
        <span class="nav-icon">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>

    <div class="nav-bg">&nbsp;</div>

    <nav class="nav-nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">              
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: There's something more. If you hover over the left side of the page, the links are clickable even when they are hidden. How can I fix that? I mean, disable them or hide them at all

Comment: For that, you can use `pointer-events: none` or `visibility:hidden;` on `.nav-nav` and `pointer-events: auto` or `visibility:visible;` on `.nav-check:checked ~ .nav-nav`